# Android AppWidget onUpdate on boot

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Does an onUpdate AppWidget called on boot?

I'm setting an alarm in the onUpdate and I wanted to know if the onUpdate will get called on boot or should I use the BOOT_COMPLETED intent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find anything in the docs regarding this so I just tested it out. I set a Toast in the `onUpdate()` method of my widget to see when it's triggered. After restarting the device it *got* triggered, so I assume that you don't need to use the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent, but sometimes you can't be sure enough(there is nothing against still using it).

***Edit:***

onUpdate() does get called on boot and the Android docs do cover this:

**onUpdate()**

> Called in response to the ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE and ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED broadcasts when this AppWidget provider is being asked to provide RemoteViews for a set of AppWidgets. Override this method to implement your own AppWidget functionality.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onUpdate(android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int[]))

**ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE**

> This may be sent in response to a new instance for this AppWidget provider having been instantiated, the requested update interval having lapsed, or the system booting.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just don't like adding unnecessary permisssions. :)

Comment: @Ahmad, you're welcome :) I ran across that info in the docs today and figured I would add it to the answer.